# I am trying to pass 3 variables from php to aspx. I can pass from aspx to php with no problem but I cannot pass infomation from php to aspx vb.net

Tags: php, asp.net

I am using this to try and pass the information.  I have seen it several times while researching but I cannot get it to work.  I only get empty values.

```
if(isset($_GET['logout'])){

//Simple exit message
    $acct = $_SESSION['acct'];
    $nam = $_SESSION['name'];
    $id = $_SESSION['empnum'];
   
    $url = "message.aspx";
    $param = "?" . "Name=" .$nam . "&Account=" .$acct . "&ID=" .$id ;
    header('Location: ' . $url . $param);
```

Can anyone see what I have done wrong?  Thanks.
I changed the $param code

```
 $url = "message.aspx" ;
 $param = "?Name=$nam&Account=$acct&ID=$id" ;
 header('Location: ' . $url . $param);
```

when I run it on my local computer the variables are there.  When I run it on the remote server the variable are gone.  Locally I cannot see the message.aspx page but I get the message

The requested resource /

> message.aspx?Name=Support&Account=9999&ID=c-1441 was not found on this
> server.

It shows the variables. I do not have the aspx file available in this project.

Comment: What do you see in your browser when you look at the query string? Is it just keys with no values?

Comment: You mean empty values in the URL? Presumably then, the session variables had no value at the time you ran the code. We of course cannot say why that is, from what you've provided so far

Comment: Yes, I just get empty values.  I see "message.aspx?Name=&Account=&ID="   I have tried changing the $param to "?Name=$nam&Account=$acct&ID=$id"   This works on the local server but not on the remote server.

Comment: I suggest reading a tutorial or two on PHP sessions.

Comment: You need to debug the code and work out why the session doesn't contain what you expected it to.

Comment: Thanks all.  I figured it out using cookies.  I appreciate the help.